Computer PSU Intermittent under load to PCIe Slot
So I am trying to use a computer PSU as a stand alone power supply. I have a Seasonic Focus+ 1000W gold PSU that I am trying to use to power some 12V monitors. I modded it slightly to accommodate the needs of the project. I soldered the PS-on to the ground pin instead of the traditional jumper wire in the connector. There was a small PCB that has the power receptacle, a few capacitors, resistors and an IC for a “magic switch” which looked like an IC containing 2 MOSFETS that I removed and immediately plugged the 120VAC into the L and N in the board.
With these mods I am having an issue with intermittent power coming out of the PSU. From testing it appears that if there is a load on the PCIe receptacle, which I am trying to use for 12V power, when I turn the supply on I get 0V output, but if there is no PCIe load and then the supply is plugged in the power will work normally. There is also the issue I’m having where the supply seems to keep a memory of the state. By this I mean that if it is in the 0V output state it will stay like that for a while, I’m assuming this is related to the draining of the capacitors in the supply.
Ultimately, I’m looking to see if anyone has any insight to possible solutions. I was reading that sometimes they require the a load on the motherboard to output so I order several 5W resistors to try and simulate, a small load 5-10W. Is more load required? This wouldn’t be an issue as I have 1000W to play with, I saw that typical motherboards are 25-40W. Some sort of switch to ground out a capacitor so it will drain faster and dump the memory?

Are you sure your load is connected correctly. Sounds like a short or polarity inversion tripping some form of overcurrent/short circuit protection.

Yes, it will turn on correctly sometimes and power them. It is just intermittent.

I kind of fail to follow all the complexities of your "rework". Why don't just a put a toggle switch on PS_ON signal and call it a day? Most likely the PSU needs some internal stable voltage on internal PS_ON supervisory circuit, and when you keep it shorted at the very beginning, power-on sequence and voltage ramping has some timing roughness. It is very likely that the "small PCB" provides the necessary delay between +5V_STB voltage and activation of PS_ON signal.

Do you have any load on the +5V rail? Many computer power supplies will not guarantee proper regulation without a minimum load on +5V.
